# Rewrite a link, mod_rewrite

Tags: php, html, apache, mod-rewrite

In shop, I have categories and products, for example. Categories are formed as

```
localhost/categories.php?categoryid=***
```

where categoryid can be ANY WORD.

Products are formed as

```
localhost/products.php?categoryid=***&productmanufactor=***&productname=***
```

where `categoryid`, `productmanufactor` and `productname` can be any words too

So I want to rewrite from (example):

`localhost/car` to `localhost/categories.php?categoryid=car` EXCEPT SOME WORDS (about, contacts, etc)

and

```
localhost/car/audi/r8
```

to

```
localhost/products.php?categoryid=car&productmanufactor=audi&productname=r8
```

How this can be done easily?

***htaccess***

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^about$           about.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^contact$         contact.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$            categories.php?categoryid=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$  products.php?categoryid=$1&productmanufactor=$2&productname=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^about$           about.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^contact$         contact.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$            categories.php?categoryid=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: You choose what you want to rewrite, this are the rules, I've made you for 3 situation, removed for just 2.

Comment: For other pages add rule before the last rule.

Comment: Add some conditions, like in my post

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still cant get it work. 
my htaccess
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^about$           about.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$            categories.php?categoryid=$1 [L]`

Every word redirects to categories.php, even about. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Try with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Comment: Tried but no changes, my htaccess is above in the 1 message, dont understand where am I wrong

Comment: So do I, I`m using MacOs and MAMP server. If I try to go to `localhost/about` it still searches for categories.php O_o

Comment: If I delete the last string - about work. Don`t know where I am wrong.

Comment: I've just tested the code above and works perfect. If file does not exist it goes to /categories.php?categoryid=xxxx, if file exists it displays, file /about it display about.php

Comment: Tried on Windows PC, on WAMP server - the same thing, can you please send me your file?

Comment: [Here is my test](http://getqr.eu/test/) and [htaccess](http://getqr.eu/test/htaccess.txt)

Comment: can you send me index.php code, 
mine still doesnt work, f**** piece of shit.

Comment: it's not blank [index.php](http://getqr.eu/test/), [/about](http://getqr.eu/about), [product](http://getqr.eu/test/aaa/aaa/aaa), [category](http://getqr.eu/test/aaa). Maybe you have some bad rules in your `httpd.conf`?

Comment: maybe there because I have the same code on 2 different PCs and they both work wrong, what am I to add to httpd.conf ?

Comment: THANKS MAN, I finally got it to work. The reason why it didnt work for me - I didnt create about.php or contact.php. 
Big, huge thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Below code may help.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /products.php?categoryid=$1&productmanufactor=$2&productname=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /categories.php?categoryid=$1 [L]
```

Also check http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/ i am using this site to generate htaccess, it is simple to use.